# Restrict Drupal view access by role

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-views-relationship

I would expect this would be easy but I can't seem to figure it out. Simple problem. I want to restrict access to a Drupal view as follows:

- Only current users who are members of a custom role may access the view

OR

- The view only displays content that is authored by the current user

The latter is easy, but restricting via current role is more problematic. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

When you're looking at the Views admin screen (admin/structure/views/view/YOUR-VIEW/edit), look in the middle column and you should see an 'Access' option under the Page Settings heading. I believe by default it's set to Permission | Views Published Content; however, if you click Permission, you can then change this to Role, and select the desired role(s) that should be able to view this content. Hope that makes sense!